# Get branch name of an installed package directly from the Julia package manager

Tags: julia, package-managers

**Intro**
A package have different build functions for different branches, to simplified git repository maintenance, I want to make building code exactly the same in all branches but check current branch as a part of building, then choose the correct procedure. `Pkg.status()` prints branch name but it do not return it.
**Question**
How to get the branch name for an installed package using package manager?

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to elaborate a little bit, git branch will give you on which branch you are. May be you already know this.

Comment: The tags show that the question was about how to do this directly from the Julia package manager, though I agree that this could have been clearer in the question  itself.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to `Pkg.status()` [code](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/pkg/entry.jl#L158) the answer could be

```
prepo = LibGit2.GitRepo(abspath(Pkg.dir(), package))
phead = LibGit2.head(prepo)
branchname = LibGit2.shortname(phead)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reza Afzalan's answer is correct, While some API have been modified since then. I add this answer since I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Let's say we try to develop `VideoIO` package and ensure that we are in correct developing branch:

```
import VideoIO

import LibGit2

pkg_path = splitdir(splitdir(pathof(VideoIO))[1])[1]
prepo = LibGit2.GitRepo(pkg_path)
phead = LibGit2.head(prepo)
branchname = LibGit2.shortname(phead)
```